# Detect for...of Loop Support in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6

Is this possible? Example:

```js
var parts = [1,2,3,4,5];
for (part of parts) {
    console.debug(part);
}
```

I want to detect if doing this is possible.

Comment: Also, http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/. [Source](https://github.com/kangax/es5-compat-table/blob/1b978c9403b281e3c6bbdbcee2b6f1eda561cd07/es6/index.html#L409-L417).

Comment: If you hover over the (C) icon in the table @JonathanLonowski links to, it shows the source of his test for that feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can always try-catch such stuff. But you need `eval` as well, as some javascript engines will bail with a SyntaxError early.

```
try {
  eval("for (var i of []);");
  console.log("yep");
} catch(ex) {
  console.log("nope");
}
```

Tested in Firefox ("yep") and Chrome ("nope").